# Java custom ordering for Sort

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

What is the best (in terms of both time and space efficiency) way to implement a Java comparator for sorting collections using custom ordering. For example - I want to sort arrays using the following ordering -

RWQOJMVAHBSGZXNTCIEKUPDYFL

I have the following Java code which works as expected but not sure if there is any other efficient way to do the same.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.lang.Math;

public class DiffSort {

    private static String order = "RWQOJMVAHBSGZXNTCIEKUPDYFL";

    // sort with comparator
    public static Comparator<String> diffNaturalOrder = new Comparator<String>() {
        public int compare(String v, String w) {
            int diff = 0, iter = 0;
            Integer index1, index2;
            Integer len1 = v.length();
            Integer len2 = w.length();
            int len = Math.min(len1, len2); // lesser of 2 strings

            for(int i=0; i<len; i++) {
                index1 = order.indexOf(v.charAt(i));
                index2 = order.indexOf(w.charAt(i));
                // if both chars are absent in order string, use natural ordering
                if(index1 == -1 && index2 == -1)
                    diff = new Character(v.charAt(i)).compareTo(new Character(w.charAt(i)));
                else if(index1 == -1 && index2 > 0)
                    diff = 1;
                else if(index1 > 0 && index2 == -1)
                    diff = -1;
                else
                    diff = index1.compareTo(index2);
                // break if we found mismatch
                if(diff != 0) break;
            }

            // return smaller string first in sort
            if(diff == 0)
                diff = len1.compareTo(len2);
            return diff;
        }
    };

    // test client
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("ABCE1!4");
        list.add("ABCE1!7");
        list.add("!SDF");
        list.add("TRWESF!");
        Collections.sort(list, DiffSort.diffNaturalOrder);

        // print sorted array
        for(String s:list)
            System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

/* OUTPUT */

ABCE1!4

ABCE1!7

TRWESF!

!SDF

Comment: I don't think you code will always sort ABC and ABCDEF correctly because it ignores the DEF and says they are equal.

Comment: As an aside, there's no such thing as 'custom natural ordering.' Natural ordering is what you get without any custom comparator.

Comment: "RWQOJMVAHBSGZXNTCIEKUPDYFL" is not a natural order! It is a custom order. And like Tom G said, there is no custom natural order!

Comment: Thanks @TomG... Edited question to reflect this...

Comment: I'm also wondering what should happen for characters not in the natural order string. Are they supposed to be sorted the same? Should they sorted as themselves? What?

Comment: One more thought. What about accented characters and upper/lower case characters? It brings up the question of how you tell your sort code that more than one character is equal in the sort. The string doesn't allow two to be equal. Each one is less than the ones after it and greater than the ones after it.

Comment: @LeeMeador... You are right... I just changed the code to fix the length checking. Also I am not worried about case sensitivity right now as I am more concerned about the efficiency and I can easilt add sensitivity check. Also if the characters fall outside the order string, they should be sorted as usual.

Comment: You are sorting them now as equal because the `indexOf()` returns -1.

Answer (score 5):

Put all of the characters of `order` in a `Map<Character, Integer>` (where the integer corresponds to the character's position in `order`) and then in your `for`-loop, instead of `order.indexOf(c)` use `map.get(c)`.

You can set up this map fairly easily:

```
private static final Map<Character, Integer> map = 
                                new HashMap<Character, Integer>(order.length());

static {
    for (int i = 0; i < order.length(); i++)
        map.put(order.charAt(i), i);
}
```

Comment: Its exactly the same idea as yours, but an array would be faster. Put -1 everywhere. Then put the index from the natural order string into the array indexed by the `charAt()`.

Comment: Just noticed the array may be a better idea depending on the character set. If you have to use full Unicode, that array gets large.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do additionally is to cache the calculation of position off char.

First w would compare that chars are equal before check in map.

Then in map would store each combination of char.

(left, right)

if left is earlier then return 1
 if right is earlier then return -1
 if left eq right return 0.

Or you could crate an char array and under position of char store the order.

```
public final class CustomAlphabetComparator implements Comparator<String> {

        private char order[] = new char[1<<16];


        public CustomAlphabetComparator (String alphabet) {
            if (alphabet == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input must not be null");

            char index = 0;

            for(char c : alphabet.toCharArray()) {
                order[c] = index++;
            }
        }


        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {

            if(o1 == o2) return 0; //We check the references

            if(o1 == null && o2 == null) return  0;
            if(o1 != null && o2 == null) return  1;
            if(o1 == null && o2 != null) return -1;

            if(o1.equals(o2)) return 0; //We check that are equal

            char[] c1 = o1.toCharArray();
            char[] c2 = o2.toCharArray();

            int shortest = c1.length < c2.length ? c1.length : c2.length;
            int result = 0;

            for(int i = 0; result == 0 & i < shortest; i++ ) {

                result = order[c1[i]] - order[c2[i]];

            }

            return result;
        }

    }
```

Comment: The array idea become more complicated if you need full unicode.

Comment: In dead it is. That why this is an alternative approach. but thanks for watching ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the code you have works, but one thing to bear in mind is that String.indexOf(ch) goes through the string character by character until it finds the one it's looking for. If your string is near the end of your "alphabet", you will incur a lot of needless looping.

I'd store the ordering in a `HashMap<Character, Integer>` and pull the indexing information from that in constant time. Should be faster than looping through the whole String (for each and every character you are comparing!)...

Answer (score 0):

Here's an efficient Comparator for only uppercase English letters (which could be expanded, but not without limitations):

```
public static Comparator<String> diffNaturalOrder = new Comparator<String>() {
    private int[] order = new int[] {7, 9, 16, 22, 18, 24, 11, 8, 17, 4, 19, 25, 5, 14, 3, 21, 2, 0, 10, 15, 20, 6, 1, 13, 23, 12};
    public int compare(String v, String w) {
        int diff = 0;
        int len = Math.min(v.length(), w.length()); // lesser of 2 strings
        int o1, o2;
        for(int i=0; i<len; i++) {
            o1 = order[v.charAt(i)-65];
            o2 = order[w.charAt(i)-65];
            diff = o1 - o2;
            // break if we found mismatch
            if(diff != 0) break;
        }
        if (diff == 0) {
            diff = v.length() - w.length();
        }
        return diff;
    }
};
```

Rather than `indexOf` or a `Map<Character, Integer>`, this uses the integer value of a char (less 65) to index into an array which contains the ordering data. The array can be generated as such:

```
private static void generateArray() {
    String order = "RWQOJMVAHBSGZXNTCIEKUPDYFL";
    int[] chars = new int[26];
    int i = 0;
    for (char c : order.toCharArray()) {
        chars[c-65] = i++;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(chars));
}
```